# Go forward to first alphabetic character

Tags: macro, navigation

Is there a way to go forward to the first letter, maybe using <kbd>f</kbd> other than specifying the letter itself?

In other words I want to skip over whitespace, symbols and digits.

The reason I ask is that I want to make a macro and different sentences might begin with different letters, so I cannot put a particular letter in the macro. I need some way to say 'skip over everything that is not a letter' in the macro.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't do `/\a<cr>`?

Comment: then use a search.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Adding a newline to a macro is tricky enough that it deserves a full explanation, if you're interested. You have to use `^V^M` to record it, and that works slightly differently in the terminal than in GVim.

Comment: Do you need it to only find characters in the same line (as implied by your mention of `f`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on DLMcMMayhem's [hint](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12931/7547#comment-22228), I found that following search will do what you need:

```
/\A*\zs\a
```

- `\A*` searches for zero or more non-alphabetic characters (equivalent to `[^A-Za-z]`)
- `\a` searches for any alphabetic character (equivalent to `[A-Za-z]`)
- `\zs` is a zero-width match (i.e. matches nothing) but tells the regex engine to reset the start of the match to the current position.

  - When moving to a match with `n`, the cursor will move to this position
  - When `hlsearch` is turned on, the highlighting will begin at this position

### Mapping

If you need to use this frequently, you can set up a mapping in your `.vimrc`. This can be a bit tricky, because there are multiple ways to insert a keyboard code, some of which will only work in Vim (not GVim).

The easiest, most compatible way is to type out the following characters into your `.vimrc`, verbatim:

```
map <silent> <S-F11> /\A\zs\a<cr>
```

- `map` sets up a keyboard mapping
- The `<silent>` flag tells `map` not to echo the command when it executes
- `<S-F11>` means <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

  If you're unsure how to spell a key, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then the key you want to map to, which will generate a unique code for any key chosen. The codes generated in terminal Vim, however, will be unique to that terminal and are not portable; specifically, they do not work in GVim.
- Finally comes the keys we want the mapping to type out for us when we use the mapping key

  - The `<cr>` represents <kbd>Enter</kbd>; it's required because you type <kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform a search action

#### Edit

- 2018-09-17 Add `*` to regex

Comment: Ok, to use this in a macro, would I first need to map this to a key and then use the key in a macro, or can I just type this into the macro directly?

Comment: @TylerDurden I forgot about the macro. Actually, just type the search as normal while recording the macro. That should work, and will continue to work even if you re-map (or forget to map) the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @TylerDurden Stopped by to make an obvious (and quite late) edit to my answer. Did you ever find a working solution?

Comment: @jpaugh Why did you add \A* when \a works? With \A* wouldn't the search not work as expected if the first character in the line was alphabetic?

Comment: @Steve, Tyler needs to match the first alphabetic character, so we must ensure no alphabetic character precedes the `\a` match. My original regex, `\A\zs\a`, works in most cases, but does not match an alphabetic character at the beginning of the line. Thus, the `*`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There's `w` (mnemonic: *word*) which moves to the beginning of the next word, and `b` (*backward*) which moves to the beginning of the previous word. Then there's `e` which moves to the end of the next word, and `ge` which moves to the end of the previous word.

You can change which characters are considered part of a word using the `iskeyword` option, and many filetype syntax plugins will set this to the characters which are allowed in identifiers for that language.

There's capital letter variants (like `W`) which counts any non-space character as a word.

Comment: Downvoter: What did I miss?

Comment: I did not downvote you, but be aware that 'w' will move forwards to symbols and digits, not just letters.

Comment: @TylerDurden It also counts `-` as its own word, at least by default. Changing its behavior with `iskeyword` is probably a necessity. (I guess that's what I get for posting an incomplete answer at first.)